# python, chrome driver errors

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I have this file test.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

I want to get the page source from the page with this python code. I'm using chrome driver selenium and python. But when I start this script I've got this error:

```
 File "test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir
```

I tried almost every solution on the internet but every time I'm just having other errors, does someone know what should I do in this situation, any advice on how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066670/cannot-create-temp-dir-for-user-data-dir-error-when-not-running-as-admin)?

Comment: What have you tried? where is your chromedriver.exe?

Comment: i dont know where is chromedriver.exe , im working on my client server so i dont know is there an option to find out the path? @MosheSlavin

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have correct chrome browser installed and correct supportive version of chromedriver
and here is some code edit suggestions

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: this also gives an error that i described in the first comment :(

Comment: you sure you have correct version of chrome and chromedriver with proper permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Try set the path driver , like bellow .... locate with this command :
whereis chromedriver

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
'

Comment: wait , but which is your path from the chromedriver?

Comment: I dont know, how i can found that?

Comment: in your console type :  whereis chromedriver

Comment: chromedriver: /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

Comment: ok , then try in the last line with driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

Comment: File "test3.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

Comment: which is the version from Google Chrome and chromedriver ?

Comment: how i can check that? this is the server from my client so i dont know