# unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir in Laravel with Symfony Panther

Tags: php, laravel, windows, selenium-webdriver, symfony-panther

i am using Symfony Panther with Laravel framework. I got an error while using this

> unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException(code: 0):

**I have installed XAMPP for Windows 7.4.2.**

**PHP: 7.4.2, Apache: 2.4.41**

composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fabpot/goutte": "^3.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^4.4",
        "symfony/http-client": "^4.4",
        "symfony/panther": "^0.7.0"
    }
```

### Laravel Controller Class

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

include (base_path() .'/vendor/autoload.php');
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\HttpBrowser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function myFunction(Request $request)
    {
        $client = \Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::createChromeClient();

        $client->request('GET', 'https://api-platform.com'); // Yes, this website is 100% written in JavaScript
        $client->clickLink('Support');

        // Wait for an element to be rendered
        $crawler = $client->waitFor('.support');

        echo $crawler->filter('.support')->text();
    }
}
```

> [2020-02-27 16:12:21] local.ERROR: unknown error: cannot create temp
>   dir for user data dir {"exception":"[object]
>   (Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException(code: 0):
>   unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir at
>   D:\WWW\PHP\myproject\vendor\php-webdriver\webdriver\lib\Exception\WebDriverException.php:139)

Comment: try deleting your vendor file, and reinstalling your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that your disk is not running low on space.
2. Does XAMPP have the correct permissions? It may be required to run with elevated permissions.
3. Check the `%TEMP%` and `%TMP%` environment variables and ensure they exist. (To do this, run `echo %TEMP%` and `echo %TMP%` on the Windows' command line)

> ***Related:*** ["cannot create temp dir for user data dir" error when not running as admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066670/cannot-create-temp-dir-for-user-data-dir-error-when-not-running-as-admin)

Comment: I have checked the above things. Still i am getting the same error.