# I get error 'cannot create temp dir for unpacking extensions' when using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-18.04

I ran a web scraper python program using Chromium driver in Selenium. I ran it in a remote server (running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) for 3-4 days as it was a data collection task. Suddenly I got this error stating that I cannot create temp dir for unpacking extensions. I have searched for similar issues but did not find any solution for this error. How would I fix this?

Thanks in advance!!

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sele.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver',options=options)
  File "/home/akileshvar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/akileshvar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/akileshvar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/akileshvar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/akileshvar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot create temp dir for unpacking extensions
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["cannot create temp dir for user data dir" error when not running as admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066670/cannot-create-temp-dir-for-user-data-dir-error-when-not-running-as-admin)

Comment: have you checked the space left on the disk?

Comment: @fpietka yes I checked the space left on the disk, you mean the secondary storage right? if it so, more than a TB was available.

Comment: @qWx No, that one didn't answer my question. And it was a different error and it all suggested for a windows machine.